# Raspberry pi one as vpn router

Tags: connection, vpn

I have a router that is connected to a modem. All connected devices have internet access through the router. I would like to connect a raspberry pi (version one, model B) to this network via cable, and connect to a VPN service so that the Pi accesses the web through this VPN. What I would like to do next is to share this connection so that the selected devices can be configured to go through the VPN instead of the normal LAN and can still see other devices inside the network.

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect to a VPN service"? What type of service? More specifically, how it is it provided and how to do you connect to it?

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand what you are trying to do.  But it would be my understanding that it is not the Raspberry Pi that controls the client's ability to use the Raspberry Pi's VPN  while still being able to see other devices on the local subnet.   It is up to the client.